# What is the correct name for interface with multiple callbacks?

Tags: design-patterns, naming-conventions, naming

Given the nature of the following, what is the best name for the interface? and if applicable which design pattern is this?

```
public interface ITestEvent??? {   // Handler / Listener / Observer / Emitter / ???

    void OnBeginTesting(ITestContext context);
    void OnException(Exception ex);
    void OnEndTesting();

}

public class MyTestEvent??? : ITestEvent { ... }

Tester.Add???(new MyTestEvent???());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially I felt it was `Command`, where you're encapsulating a testing request, and invoking/queuing it with Tester.Add().

But after your feedback, I realize that you're simply passing-in behavior; so I agree with @kabram that this is **`Delegate`**.

Comment: I should clarify, each of the methods inside `ITestEvent???` are invoked to provide and log feedback at each of those stages of the testing process and cannot alter the testing process in any way. For example `OnBeginTesting` could be implemented as `Console.WriteLine("Testing process has begun.");`

Comment: OK, it seems like you're simply passing-in behavior, so I'd probably agree with @kabram that this is Delegate.

Comment: Dave and @kabram thanks for your help, if one of you guys make that an answer then I will accept it.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect the clarification. :)